# Displaying results on results page, SQL ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Here is my query string that has no errors.

```
    con.Open();
    string mysql; // generate an sql insert query for the database
    mysql = "SELECT * FROM Cars WHERE Make LIKE (?)";
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(mysql, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", tbMake.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    Response.Redirect("results.aspx");
```

..but unsure how I transfer the data to another page to read, and how I can display this as data grid views retrieve direct from the database?

I have a datagridview on the results page named "SearchDataGrid" and a dataset named "Search.xsd"

Thanks.

Comment: Why this response redirect ? what are you exactly trying to achieve ? There are many ways to display data onto an asp.net page. You could for example look into gridviews, try some code, and then come back here if you got a problem.

Comment: Where is `@p1` parameter in your command string?

Comment: I'm using an access database so it requires using "?". The issue isn't my query string but how to connect the results to my dataset for viewing on my datagridview on the results page.

Comment: Use `Server.Transfer` and access `tbMake.Text` via `PreviousPage` property, then execute  this query on `results.aspx` instead of the first page.

Comment: How would I output the results of my query into the "SearchDataGrid" datagridview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Go through following code:**

```
    try
    { 
    con.Open();
    string mysql; // generate an sql insert query for the database
    mysql = "SELECT * FROM Cars WHERE Make LIKE (@p1)";
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(mysql, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", tbMake.Text);
    OleDbDataAdapter da=new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds=new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    gv.DataSourse=ds.Tables[0];
    gv.DataBind();
    con.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
     con.close();
    }
```

Hope Its Helpful.

Comment: This won't send the results to the "results.aspx" page though will it, I like what you've shown though I will implement it thank you.

Comment: Dataset is missing a reference? and gv doesn't exist in the current context. Are my errors with this?

Comment: you must give your gridview name as 'gv' and you will have to import necessary files for Dataset

Comment: I have a data set called, "search.xsd" and the code above. I'll create a grid view on the results page. What connects it all together?

Comment: If you have directly data set as .xsd , then go to the properties of gridview , in that select Datasourse>>otherdatasourses>>project datasourses>>and select search.xsd

Comment: How does the search page send data to the dataset?

Comment: Surely it can be done without a dataset, but simply query the database through my query string and just output in the gridview on the results page...

Comment: Declare one public static string str variable in search page. Take the value of tbMake.Text in str[String] and pass it to dataset parameter

Comment: No idea what that means, all I want to do is show the results of my query string on a results page, surely it can't be that difficult?

Comment: How do I pass it into the dataset, it makes sense but this wizard thing when setting up the dataset annoys me. Try to avoid the setup wizards.

Comment: just declare public static variable and take value in text box. Then compile it. It will give you error something like>> Function takes more than 1 parameter. Double click on error. Add that public variable as a parameter to that method.

Comment: I'm new to this, I don't understand what you are trying to say. Do you know any websites with easy tutorials?

Comment: www.youtube.com/watch?v=QERuo8L6J4U

Answer (score 0):

This isn't remotely close. You can however follow these steps:

1. Put a gridview on your asp.net page.
2. Implement a function that will return a dataset or datatable.
3. Set the datasource of your gridview to your datatable.

**UPDATE** : Using xsd wouldn't be my first choice but, if you want to:

From the designer

1. In properties of GridView, from the DataSourceID, choose "New Data Source"
2. It will open "Data Source Configuration Wizard"
3. Select "Object" from the list then OK. "Configure Datasource Wizard" will be opened
4. Choose your xsd file name from the dropdown and follow the steps.

Comment: I made a dataset, name "search.xsd" have a datagridview called "SearchDataGrid" on my results page. Not sure how to connect my query to the dataset for viewing on the results page.